# How to move data from one database to another database

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to move selected tables from SOURCE data base to DESTINATION database.?
could any one please give me idea to complete the task. As i  am in learning stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
INSERT INTO Destination.dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
    SELECT 
        COl1, Col2, ....., ColN
    FROM
        Source.dbo.YourTable
    WHERE
        (your conditions here)
```

You might need to set up a server link between the two machines (see: [MSDN Linking Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)), and they need to be "reachable" to each other, e.g. in the same network/corporate LAN.